# NSURLConnection, authorization on remote server in Swift

Tags: nsstring, swift, nsurlconnection, ios8

This is sample code. I have an error in string:

`var theReply = String.stringWithBytes(GETReply.bytes, length: GETReply.length, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)`

Error:

`Could not find an overload for '_conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments`

What is wrong?

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !loginL.text.isEmpty || !passL.text.isEmpty {
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        var login = loginL.text.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var pass = passL.text.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var stringURL = "http://nakhimov.info/iosdev/user.php?t=1&l=\(login)&p=\(pass)"
        NSLog("URL string for login: \(stringURL)")

        var webURL = stringURL.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.URL = NSURL.URLWithString(webURL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var responce:NSURLResponse?
        let GETReply:NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &responce, error: nil)
        var theReply = String.stringWithBytes(GETReply.bytes, length: GETReply.length, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        var wrong = "ERROR"

        if theReply == wrong {
            myAlertShow("ERROR!", message: "Login or password is invalid")
        }
        else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("closeZoneSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }

    resetToDefaults()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! :-)

```
var theReply = NSString(bytes: GETReply.bytes, length: GETReply.length, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```